# How to re-open a popup Leaflet Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, popup, leaflet

I have popups located at particular coordinates on the map. I'm using the SnakeAnim code to animate a route and when the route reaches the coordinate, the popup opens up. However, I want the route to be animated twice and the pop up to open twice and this does not occur with the following code.

```
var Bra = [ -22.7837 , -43.1315 ],
    Ind = [ 17.53 , 73.14 ];

var mBra = L.marker(Bra).setOpacity(0),
    mInd = L.marker(Ind).setOpacity(0);
```

The animation consists of plotting polylines and animating them using [snakeAnim](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim). So if BRA is the route to go to Brazil and IND the one to India, I'd have

```
var pathmat = L.featureGroup([L.polyline(BRA), mBra, L.polyline(IND), mInd, L.polyline(BRA), mBra]);
var map = L.map('map');
map.addLayer(pathmat);

function snake() 
{               
    pathmat.snakeIn();  
}
pathmat.on('snakestart snake snakeend', function(ev){
console.log(ev.type);
```

I am currently using the method suggested by IvanSanchez.

```
function wait() {
  map.closePopup()
};
mBra.on('add', function() {
  map.openPopup('Brazil', Bra);
  setTimeout(wait, 2000);
});
mInd.on('add', function() {
  map.openPopup('India', Ind);
  setTimeout(wait, 2000);
});
mBra.on('add', function() {
  map.openPopup('Brazil', Bra);
  setTimeout(wait, 2000);
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Please share what are your other variables (`mBra`, `Bra`, etc.) and ideally provide a live test case, e.g. using JSFiddle, Plunker, JSBin, etc.

Comment: I have made the edits @ghybs